# Unable to set Singularity grid total to 16

Tags: theming

I’m having a problem using the Singularity grid framework. I set the total number of columns to 16 but it seems not to be reading this setting. instead the total seems to be 12.

the details are as follows. 
I’m using the Omega theme and have correctly implemented a sub-theme
i’m using SASS and in the grid partial, _grid.scss have this code

```
@import "singularitygs";
$tab: 44em; /*704 pixels */
$desk: 70em; /* 1120 pixels */
$grids:16;
$gutters:1/4;
```

for test purposes i set a div to be 16 columns with this code.

```
.someDiv {@include grid-span(16, 1); }
```

this div then breaks out of the main page div, in this case .l-page and in the inspector it reads as

```
width:133%;
```

to trouble shoot i’ve searched via grep ‘grids:12’ and cleared the .sass-cache file. but so far nothing is working. has anyone had this same problem?

Comment: What version of Omega?

Comment: oh good point. Omega 4, sorry not to include that earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are using the correct syntax for your version of SingularityGS. Your syntax is for [pre 1.2](https://github.com/at-import/Singularity/wiki/Creating-Grids#symmetric-grids). If you created the sub-theme recently, I bet you are on a more modern version. The syntax should be like:

```
// Singularity 1.2+ Syntax
@include add-grid(16);
@include add-gutter(1/4);
```

It is also very unlikely that .sass-cache files are causing your issues.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you aren't overwriting your grids variable.  I believe that by default, it's overwritten when the browser reaches the $tab size via: `$grids: add-grid(12 at $tab);` so searching for that line would be a start.

To help visualize your grid, singularitygs has the `@include background-grid($color: blue);` option that might be helpful while testing.

Lastly, you can always set your grids on the fly with a 3rd argument in your `grid-span` calls.  For example:

```
// Override the default $grids variable to use 16 grids
@include grid-span(16, 1, 16);
```